# Laravel unique validation in request with other fields WITHIN that request?

Tags: laravel, validation, request

`I want to make a unique validaiton against the following fields

- `email` - from `Users` table
- `shop_id` - from `Staff` table
- `staff_roles` sent via an array of strings e.g `["shop_manager", "shop_cleaner"]`. If any email/shop_id/role exists already the request should not be valid - from `StaffRoles` table

If a combination of those fields exists in the DB, the request should be considered invalid.

Here's my `AddStaffRequest`:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'shop_id' => ['required', 'uuid'],
        'email' => ['required', 'email'],
        'staff_roles' => ['array'],
        'staff_roles.*' => ['string'],
    ];
}
```

Is there a simple solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a `"after"` validator:

```
/**
 * Configure the validator instance.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Validation\Validator  $validator
 * @return void
 */
public function withValidator($validator)
{
    $validator->after(function ($validator) {
        $attributes = $validator->attributes();
        if (StaffRoles::where([
            ['email', $attributes['email']],
            ['shop_id', $attributes['shop_id']],
            ['role', $attributes['role']]])->count() != 0) 
        {
            $validator->errors()->add('constraint_name', 'the combinations already exists');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Genius. Thanks Berto99.

Answer (score 0):

What about assembling a query which would validate the request, given the fact that this is a tad more complex logic?

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
    'email' => [
        'required',
        Rule::exists('staff')->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('account_id', 1);
        }),
    ],
]);
```

Comment: I would seriously 
discourage this solution, since indexes have nothing to do with input validation

Comment: Yep, I have that. However I'd prefer to catch this in the Request rather than let it go all the way through the controller, service, to the DB to raise an exception. Is that possible?

Comment: Also it's not on the same table. `email` is on Users, `shop_id` is from Staff, and `staff_role` is from StaffRoles

Comment: Edited the answer